# How to find all movies in laptop?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

Is there a way to find all movie files in my laptop (Windows Vista)?

I have stored them on so many places. currently I don't know what to do and how to find those?

Comment: Try this AQS query in the search box: `kind:video`. See this handy search syntax reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also try using [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/). It'll show all your files as colored rectangles. Bigger rectangles will show bigger files. On the right, you'll have a list of extensions. This way you'll be able to select all files of certain type by clicking on their extension on the right and graphically see their size.

Comment: +1 True, this would be a good overview to know where everything is. The only problem is that this takes long to scan and consumes a lot of memory...

Comment: @TomWij: True, but you usually only need to do it once, then you know where stuff is...

Answer (score 8):

Use [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) and search for the following:

`*.3gp | *.avi | *.flv | *.mkv | *.mov | *.mpg | *.rm |  *.vob | *.wmv`

Or only list the file extensions that you think it could be, I listed the most popular.

Movies tend to be big so you could sort on the size column to get them together...

Answer (score 5):

The regular Windows Vista search can do that, just search for video filetypes. Another great and quick alternative is [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) from voidtools. You can use filters like `*.avi` to narrow files down to just AVI for example.

Answer (score 3):

Some times Windows is not as user friendly as it is supposed to be – for example, i wanted to find all the pictures in my computer.

The search in Windows 7 is not so clear on how to perform this task ( XP had this feature )

To search for all “certain kind” of media or files you can do the following trick

Go to the folder you want to search.

On the search bar to the top-right type "kind". You should see a dropdown of various kinds of search criteria – choose the one you want and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

- If you want to find all pictures, the search would be `kind:=picture`
- If you want to search for pictures and something else then it would be `kind:=music OR kind:=pictures OR kind:=videos`

Answer (score 2):

1. Run `cmd`
2. `cd \`
3. Use the this command: `dir *.avi, *.flv, *.mkv, *.rm /s /b` or `dir *.avi, *.flv, *.mkv, *.rm /s /b >playlist.txt` to pipe it to a file.

These file extensions are just sample. You can add more.

Comment: Then he have to find this separately for each partition by typing this and what if he has many partition?

Answer (score 1):

Hello I find that in my file explorer this works well:

kind:=video    to find all movies

kind:=music    to find all audio files

kind:=picture    to find all images